# downsampling gps data using haversine formula using python

Tags: python, pandas, gps, haversine, downsampling

I have a high frequency of gps data which i want to downsample to every 50 meters ie keep gps latitude and longitude every 50 meter and discard inbetween points. I found a python code on the internet which basically calculates the distance between two points. But i am not sure how to basically read from a csv the lat and long values and feed it into the function and calculate the distance. If the distance reaches 50 meter i simply save that gps coordinates. So far, i have the following python code

```
from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt
def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])

    # haversine formula 
    dlon = lon2 - lon1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
    r = 6371 # Radius of earth in kilometers. Use 3956 for miles
    return c * r

x1 = 52.19421607 
x2 = 52.20000327 
y1 = -1.484984011 
y2 = -1.48533465
result = haversine(x1,y1,x2,y2)    #need to give input from a csv
#if result is greater than 50m , save the coordinates
print(result)
```

How can i solve the problem?Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module to read your file. Or you can use [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) method if you want to use pandas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a outline and a working code example - where I made some assumptions about which to keep/drop. I assume the dataframe is sorted.

1. First calculate distance to next point, indeed use haversine for lat/long pairs. This part is not fast in my implementation - you can find faster.
2. Use `cumsum()` of distances, to create distance groups, where group 1 is all distances below 50, group 2 between 50 and 100, etc...
3. Within each group, keep for instance only the `first()`

Note that this is approximately each 50 units based on group, so be aware this is different than take a point and jump to next point which is closest to 50 units away and repeat. But for data reduction purposes it should be fine.

Generate some random data around London.

```
import numpy as np
import sklearn
import pandas as pd

LONDON =  (51.509865, -0.118092)

random_gps = np.random.random( (10000,2) ) / 25
random_gps[:,0] += np.arange(random_gps.shape[0]) / 25

random_gps[:,0] += LONDON[0]
random_gps[:,1] += LONDON[1]

gps_data = pd.DataFrame( random_gps, columns=["lat","long"] )
```

Shift the data to get the lat/long of the next point

```
gps_data['next_lat'] = gps_data.lat.shift(1)
gps_data['next_long'] = gps_data.long.shift(1)

gps_data.head()
```

Define the distance metric. This part can be improved in terms of speed by using vector expressions with numpy, so if speed is important change this part.

```
from sklearn.neighbors import DistanceMetric

dist = DistanceMetric.get_metric('haversine')

EARTH_RADIUS = 6371.009

def haversine_distance(row):
    point_a = np.array([[row.lat, row.long]])
    point_b = np.array([[row.next_lat, row.next_long]])
    return EARTH_RADIUS * dist.pairwise(np.radians(point_a), np.radians(point_b) )[0][0]
```

and apply our distance function (slow part, which can be improved)

```
gps_data["distance_to_next"] = gps_data.apply( haversine_distance, axis=1)
gps_data["distance_cumsum"] = gps_data.distance_to_next.cumsum()
```

Finally, create groups and drop. (!) The haversine is returning the distance in KM - so here i wrongly did an example of 50 km instead of meters.

```
gps_data["distance_group"] = gps_data.distance_cumsum // 50

filtered = gps_data.groupby(['distance_group']).first()
```